# How to Access user data from iCloud in webapp?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, icloud, cloudkit

I want to access the user data like Contacts , Images etc from iCloud on the webapp . Please help me out on the following query ?

1) Can i use cloudKit JS to access the data from iCloud ?

2) Is there any another way to access the data ?

Comment: Have you followed the CloudKit guide? https://developer.apple.com/reference/cloudkitjs

Comment: Your questions are answered directly in the rest of Apple's documentation for CloudKit: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloutKitWebServicesReference/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015240-CH1-SW1 - please put more effort into researching your questions before posting.